# How to automate installation using a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-installer

I'm trying to install software by booting into a Windows installation to bring up the Command Prompt.

I can't run the msi there!

```
D:\setup>setup.msi
```

It says:

```
Access Is Denied
```

Is there a way to "automate" the installation with a `.bat`?

Comment: Please answer it's getting on my nerves.

Comment: You may need to open the Command Prompt, or execute the batch file **as administrator**, _(although UAC/elevation should already be an integral part of an `.msi` which requires it)_.

Answer (score 0):

When I need UAC privilege escalation I use the following script:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights V2
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO =============================
ECHO Running Admin shell
ECHO =============================

:init
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "batchPath=%~0"
for %%k in (%0) do set batchName=%%~nk
set "vbsGetPrivileges=%temp%\OEgetPriv_%batchName%.vbs"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:checkPrivileges
NET FILE 1>NUL 2>NUL
if '%errorlevel%' == '0' ( goto gotPrivileges ) else ( goto getPrivileges )

:getPrivileges
if '%1'=='ELEV' (echo ELEV & shift /1 & goto gotPrivileges)
ECHO.
ECHO **************************************
ECHO Invoking UAC for Privilege Escalation
ECHO **************************************

ECHO Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = "ELEV " >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO For Each strArg in WScript.Arguments >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO args = args ^& strArg ^& " "  >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO Next >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
ECHO UAC.ShellExecute "!batchPath!", args, "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbsGetPrivileges%"
"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%vbsGetPrivileges%" %*
exit /B

:gotPrivileges
setlocal & pushd .
cd /d %~dp0
if '%1'=='ELEV' (del "%vbsGetPrivileges%" 1>nul 2>nul  &  shift /1)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM In this state it will Run shell as admin (example) - add your code here
ECHO %batchName% Arguments: %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
cmd /k
```

It will even give you the dialogue if the UAC settings requires it.

CREDIT : [winhelponline.com](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/automatically-elevate-batch-file-run-administrator/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a .msi file directly. You need to call `msiexec /i setup.msi`. 
See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx